# How to get information about devices that do not run Google play service?

Tags: android-versions, google-play-services

We can get information about percentage of different Android version using Google play service. Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform). Now, how can I get information about percentage of Android versions running without Google play service?

Comment: Number growing (thanks to projects like microG). But what's the purpose of a percentage? And how should there be correct numbers available without a "central counting instance"?

Comment: The purpose of finding percentage to support such Android version which cover majority of market..

Comment: While strictly speaking this is a "development question" (which would be off-topic), I think it's of concern for end-users as well (at least for those running "Google-free devices"). I don't think there is such a statistic related to Android *versions* (those will probably go with the general version distribution) – but the "overall percentage of devices running without GApps" would certainly be of interest here. Pointers: Many of them probably run *microG* (or similar) as replacement (two devices here – both my phones are configured such).